# Hard disk not working

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, bsod

I have a 500GB Hitachi Hard disk which is failing.

It sometimes detects in bios and sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes it also works maybe for 10-20 min then it stops working and I get a BSOD saying "kernel_data_inpage_error" after this when I restart the PC the hard disk doesn't show.I then replug my hard disk or PC then it shows but then it gets stuck at windows loading logo and sometime it makes it to windows.

Something is fishy though, when it fails all animation etc. works like the start menu, mouse loading icon, mouse can move around, etc. but when you try to access something from the hard it hangs and then BSOD.

Hard disk spins perfect like it supposed to. No clicking sound or anything.

What I tried:

Tried different SATA Cables

Tried 3 different PSUs

Tried cleaning its contacts with a rubber

And also tried it on another PC.

What could be the problem? Will I need to replace HDD PCB?

Here is the SMART data for the drive:

[image]

Comment: "And also tried it on another PC." ...with what result?

Comment: Stick it in another PC as a slave, and then run a SMART tool

Comment: On the other PC, it doesn't even pass the BIOS splash screen. And I also tried using "CrystalDiskInfo", it showed it was good and it's not overheating(40c). Windows default Defragment also showed the hard drive was 2% fragmented

Comment: Don't try to boot from it. Stick it in a USB enclosure & hang it off another machine to rescue your data if you don't already have a backup.

Comment: Yes, that is my plan. I am going to buy a new hard disk and then try to do some stuff with the failing hard disk.

Comment: Do heads just fail or do they fail slowly?

Comment: post a picture of this tool: http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html Looks like the HDD is damaged.

Comment: There is nothing "fishy", this is normal for a failing disk. You cannot fix a failing disk, your options are to return it or replace it. Trying to replace the PCB, unless you are a data recovery specialist, is just going break it even more.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your hard drive is failing. The most important thing you need to do is to **backup your important data**

```
You need one of the following options:
```

> **A) Another working PC**
>
> (where you will install the hard drive as *secondary drive*)
>
> **B) Another working hard drive with Windows installed**
>
> (which you
>           will use to boot in Windows, leaving the bad drive aside as *secondary drive* )

For this task, you can manually copy all your files to a safe storage or you can use a data recovery program from [this list](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/filerecovery/tp/free-file-recovery-programs.htm) to backup your data (*do not install the program on the failing drive*).

Once that is done, you can move up to the next step:**diagnose your hard drive**

For this step, i reccomend you to use [Hard Disk Sentinel](http://www.hdsentinel.com/download.php) (*again,do not install this program on the failing drive*)

It's a great program to use for failing drives, as it tells you both performance and health of the drive in precentage.
[image: An example of Hard Disk Sentinel]

> (an example of Hard Disk Sentinel)

Post down in the commnets the % of health and performance if you have backed up your data already (do not rely just on CrystalDiskInfo, use other programs).

Comment: "Master" and "slave" (technically, device 0 and device 1) are PATA terms, not SATA.

Comment: Ooh,.... I didn't noticed it was SATA :) (anyway....)

Answer (score 1):

Ok this will depend on how valuable your data is on this HDD,

Do not risk more time trying to diagnose it, get the data off to a new HDD, then you can start to diagnose it.

From what information your have provided it sounds like your OS is also on this HDD and when you try to access a file off the HDD it BSOD, I would imagine this is because its running into bad sectors on the HDD that it cannot read and if its BSOD that it maybe quite an important file to access.

You can perform a full Check Disk on the device and if there are bad sectors it maybe able to resolve it.

Get a new HDD, install that and Windows, then install the HDD as a second device to pull the data over to the new HDD, I just wouldn't risk having it on until your ready to pull the data off.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But do you have any solution for this? All I can think of is replacing the PCB

Comment: @user3284463 Why are you already worrying about replacing the HDD PCD? Do what Nick says, stop using that disk **and only bring it online again as a slave with the intent to copy data off**. If you have (new) problems in *that* configuration, ask a new question (or expand your current one).

Comment: If the smart diagnoses is returning ok, it maybe just a corrupted windows install. But that information is never going to be 100% the smart is more of a guide line. If theres data on there, get it off and reinstall windows then do some testing and then move the data back once your happy its working ok.